# Dynamically changing the proxy server for all outgoing traffic

Tags: linux, proxy

I have three proxy servers in my college, all of them are connected to three different service providers. At different instant of time, different proxies give different speed (depending the number of users using that proxy at that instant of time). I feel that changing the proxy server configuration in browser(or at any other network appl.) at different instant of time are very time-consuming. I want to write one script which can change the proxy server used by all of my network applications at different instant of time dynamically by doing some kind of test.

I am not able to start with it. Can somebody please give me some idea so that I can implement it.

Comment: Just a hint into one possible (I suppose) direction, [load-balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) might be a solution.  Since you can't do this in your college's computers, you might have to do it *locally*.

Comment: Agree sr_, he could run something light like Inlab Balance and then just connect to loopback:8080 or whatever he sets it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PROXY.PAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) or [WPAD.DAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wpad.dat)

it's just an JavaScript, you can host this file on any web server in your intranet and set in client side `http://webserever-ip/proxy.pac`. using this script you can do [load-balancing](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/7949.html) with your three proxy. also you can divide traffic using ip ranges in this java script , there are multiple feature like bypass intranet or any web site.

You can Setup this script Automatically in all your clients side , below option are required for the same

- if You are using Domain Network then set Proxy.pac using Group Policy
- You can set WPAD.DAT using DHCP
- DNS

Answer (score 0):

To configure the proxy from a single point, you could set up a router that does destination address re-writing using an iptables rule such as

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d VIRTUAL_PROXY_IP --dport 80 -j NETMAP --to CURRENT_PROXY_IP
```

All applications and browsers would would use VIRTUAL_PROXY_IP as their proxy, which you would need to route through this special router. You change the rule as needed to change the CURRENT_PROXY_IP.

The advantage to this approach is that it is quick to set up and easy to administer. The disadvantage is that there is likely to be some disruption to some users who have sessions open (depending on the type of sessions and the type of upstream proxies). You also have to either write your own script to change the proxies, or change manually.

A better solution, suggested by sr_'s comment, would be to set up a load balancer. Consider LVS or [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that you are using squid* Two sibling proxies sharing the same visible name seems to do the trick for me. I have 2 set up with the names proxy1 and proxy2 respectively. The visible hostname is proxy. All you should have to do at that point is create an A record in dns for the name proxy with the IP addresses for proxy1 and proxy1. As long as they are set up as siblings in your squid.conf. Take a look here http://horms.net/projects/redundant_linux_paper/related/squid/hierarchies/concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution**

Set up a host alias for the proxy servers in your local hosts file, such as

`192.168.1.1 chosenproxy
#192.168.1.2 chosenproxy
#192.168.1.3 chosenproxy`

Now configure all applications to use this alias `http://chosenproxy:8080`

To then try different servers, just edit the IP address in the hosts file.

**Manageable Port Solution**

If you also need to change the port, use one of the light-weight proxy programs, such as polipo.  Polipo runs by default on port 8123 so set every application to connect via polipo running locally, eg using the setting `http://localhost:8123`

Then to try a different proxy server, change the polipo configuration file (`/etc/polipo/config`) to specify the right Parent Proxy server and Port number, and restart polipo to activate the change.